# Reading a password from std::cin

Tags: c++, stl, password-protection

I need to read a password from standard input and wanted `std::cin` not to echo the characters typed by the user...

How can I disable the echo from std::cin?

here is the code that I'm currently using:

```
string passwd;
cout << "Enter the password: ";
getline( cin, passwd );
```

I'm looking for a OS agnostic way to do this.
[Here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=466009) there are ways to do this in both Windows and *nix.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687769/how-to-get-a-password-input-in-c-console-application/13687770#13687770

Answer (score 76, accepted):

@wrang-wrang answer was really good, but did not fulfill my needs, this is what my final code (which was based on [this](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=466009)) look like:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

void SetStdinEcho(bool enable = true)
{
#ifdef WIN32
    HANDLE hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); 
    DWORD mode;
    GetConsoleMode(hStdin, &mode);

    if( !enable )
        mode &= ~ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT;
    else
        mode |= ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT;

    SetConsoleMode(hStdin, mode );

#else
    struct termios tty;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &tty);
    if( !enable )
        tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    else
        tty.c_lflag |= ECHO;

    (void) tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tty);
#endif
}
```

Sample usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    SetStdinEcho(false);

    std::string password;
    std::cin >> password;

    SetStdinEcho(true);

    std::cout << password << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: gcc warns here:

/home/curtine/git/pub/sxx/src/sxx.cpp: In function ‘void set_stdin_echo(bool)’:
/home/curtine/git/pub/sxx/src/sxx.cpp:84:19: error: negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type [-Werror=sign-conversion]
       tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;

Comment: Gonna disable that warning I think

Comment: This is a good answer as far as the not echoing aspect but I have downvoted it because it reads the password into a std::string which is not secure (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698002/how-does-one-securely-clear-stdstring). Would you consider reworking it to read into a char[]? I'd happily reverse my downvote in that case.

Comment: Also, in relation to @ericcurtin's comment, I have found `&= ~(0u | ECHO)` a better way of avoiding the warning than simply disabling it. Funny API though. :-$

Comment: @nickform char[] is no more secure than a string if you don't rewrite over the data after

Comment: @ericcurtin agreed but the point is that you *can't* do that reliably with a std::string. I think that an accepted answer for a question about password handling really should exemplify best practice in as many ways as possible. I think it would be entirely reasonable not to cover the clearing of the buffer in the example though.

Comment: Just a reminder to everyone reading, StackOverflow is not professional security advice. That said, @nickform, you can easily replace the `std::cin` for a `char buffer[BUF_SIZE]; fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE, stdin);` but you will need to securely rewrite the buffer, as Eric pointed out, And if you are going to manually overwrite it you can also do it with the `std::string`. The thing you can't do is create a class that will do it automatically for you (deriving from std::string).

Comment: @Vargas why an allocator can't be used, and unique_ptr with deallocator that would zero the string object, combining both?

Answer (score 10):

There's nothing in the standard for this.

In unix, you could write some magic bytes depending on the terminal type.

Use  [getpasswd](http://docsrv.sco.com:507/en/man/html.S/getpasswd.S.html) if it's available.

You can system() `/usr/bin/stty -echo` to disable echo, and `/usr/bin/stty echo` to enable it (again, on unix).

[This guy explains](http://www.satishsvasan.com/2009/06/tty-please-dont-echo.html) how to do it without using "stty"; I didn't try it myself.

Comment: I guess `getpasswd` would really help. But I'm looking for a way to do this without recurring to OS black magic

Comment: The getpasswd link is refusing to load, and my machine doesn't have a manual entry for it. Maybe it was removed at some point? The closest equivalent is [getpass](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpass.3.html), but it's deprecated and the manual recommends setting the ECHO flag instead (i.e. [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1455007/6296561))

Answer (score 7):

If you don't care about portability, you can use `_getch()` in `VC`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    std::string password;
    char ch;
    const char ENTER = 13;

    std::cout << "enter the password: ";

    while((ch = _getch()) != ENTER)
    {
        password += ch;
        std::cout << '*';
    }
}
```

There is also `getwch()` for `wide characters`. My advice is that you use [`NCurse`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ncurses.htm) which is available in `*nix` systems also.

Answer (score 1):

Only idea what i have, you could read password char by char, and after it just print backspace ("\b") and maybe '*'.

Comment: If someone is logging the terminal output to a file then the whole password will be there. Probably not a good idea, then.

Comment: Same case as someone logging all key pressing :)

Comment: This is insecure, and a bad idea. It's inacceptable to rely on the other side of the pipe for your own security. And be careful not to pipe over the network. And logging output != logging keypress: you will typically give the log file's read userright to more people than those with the rights to write over the terminal emulator program, or to hook into terminal or system events or keyboard driver.