# C++ password masking

Tags: c++, input, passwords, masking

i'm writing a code to receive password input. Below is my code... the program run well but the problem is other keys beside than numerical and alphabet characters also being read, for example delete, insert, and etc. can i know how can i avoid it? tq...

```
string pw="";
char c=' ';

while(c != 13) //Loop until 'Enter' is pressed
{
    c = _getch();
    if(c==13)
        break;

    if(c==8)
    {
        if(pw.size()!=0)   //delete only if there is input 
        {
            cout<<"\b \b";
            pw.erase(pw.size()-1);
        }
    }

    if((c>47&&c<58)||(c>64&&c<91)||(c>96&&c<123))  //ASCii code for integer and alphabet
    {
        pw += c;
        cout << "*";
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read a password from std::cin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413445/read-a-password-from-stdcin)

Answer (score 7):

Filter using [`isalnum()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/ctype.h.html) for alpha-numeric or `isalpha()` for only alphabets.

Also, you are checking `c == 13` twice, following will suffice.

```
while(1){
  //
  if(c == 13)
    break;
  //
}
```

---

```
if( isalnum(c) ){
  // 'c' is acceptable
}
```

Some assertion is failing during execution which throws that error.

Comment: i had changed it to:
if(isalnum(c)!=0||isalpha(c)!=0)
But... now if i press key like delete or insert, the program crash and pop up a window (Debug Assertion Failed). how can i handle the assertion? tq for ur reply...

Comment: no i din assert anything... the program will crash and said assertion failed when i press others key.. i now changed my code to
    if(isalnumc(c) || isalpha(c))
it's only work well if i enter numerical or alphabet...

Comment: if i use getchar(), the password that user key in will be displayed before the '*' being displayed.. but that 1 can solve the assertion problem..

Comment: It's also important to mention that it is undefined behaviour to check ranges of chars rather than using is*().

Comment: You really do NOT want to use isalnum checks for passwords. Better check for !isctrl so people can use whitespace in their passwords.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to it, you are much better off using the GNU [`getpass`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/getpass.html) function.