# Password masking console application

Tags: c#, passwords, console-application, user-input, masking

I tried the following code...

```
string pass = "";
Console.Write("Enter your password: ");
ConsoleKeyInfo key;

do
{
    key = Console.ReadKey(true);

    // Backspace Should Not Work
    if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace)
    {
        pass += key.KeyChar;
        Console.Write("*");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("\b");
    }
}
// Stops Receving Keys Once Enter is Pressed
while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("The Password You entered is : " + pass);
```

But this way the backspace functionality doesn't work while typing the password.
Any suggestion?

Comment: I suggest you do not echo anything back to the console because that'll expose the length of the password.

Comment: @RayCheng - fair enough, but very few user interfaces (other than on some Unix systems) echo nothing at all. For consistent user experience with other apps and websites, showing the * characters is probably best.

Comment: @StephenHolt I'm fairly certain every terminal-based password input I've ever encountered chose to echo nothing to the terminal. Given the security benefits and the fact that this is a well-known convention in the Unix world, I personally think echoing nothing is the right choice, unless you believe your user base is likely to be unfamiliar with the use of terminals (in which case it's probably best to use a GUI instead anyway).

Answer (score 297, accepted):

`Console.Write("\b \b");` will delete the asterisk character from the screen, but you do not have any code within your `else` block that removes the previously entered character from your `pass` string variable.

Here's the relevant working code that should do what you require:

```
var pass = string.Empty;
ConsoleKey key;
do
{
    var keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);
    key = keyInfo.Key;

    if (key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && pass.Length > 0)
    {
        Console.Write("\b \b");
        pass = pass[0..^1];
    }
    else if (!char.IsControl(keyInfo.KeyChar))
    {
        Console.Write("*");
        pass += keyInfo.KeyChar;
    }
} while (key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
```

Comment: Oh I thought \b \b will take me two places back. Nevertheless this seems to be working prfecttly.

Comment: @Nadeem: Note the space character (`' '`) between the backspace characters (`'\b'`). `"\b \b"` takes you one place back, then prints a space (which takes you one place forward) and then takes you back again, so you end up where the deleted `'*'` character was.

Comment: @Nadeem - The first `\b` moves the cursor back one position (now underneath the last `*` char.  The `[space]` character "prints over" the asterisk, but also moves the cursor one character forward again, so the last `\b` moves the cursor back to where the last `*` used to be!  (Phew - Hope that makes sense!)

Comment: `if (pass.Length > 0)` should be `if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && pass.Length > 0)` otherwise you will not get the last character of the password..

Comment: @MemphiZ - Good catch!  Edited to reflect the fix.

Comment: If you don't want the user to be able to write control characters (like F5 or Escape), you could replace `if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace && key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)` with `if (!char.IsControl(key.KeyChar))`.

Comment: This didn't work on me. It always left an asterisk at the end. I needed to add one space before the backspace to make it work: `Console.Write(" \b \b");`

Comment: `pass.Substring(0, (pass.Length - 1))` could be simplified to `pass.Substring(0, pass.Length - 1)`

Comment: Will this work if you paste the password into the console?

Comment: I tested this and it works when you paste the password into the console as well. Thanks!

Comment: I use this so frequently I wish it was a nuget package

Comment: Do you have version for C# 7.3? This works only in C# 8.0 due to range "[0..^1]"

Comment: @JohnyCorbie If you look at the history of the answer, you'll find an alternative to using range to set the pass variable.  e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20911937

Answer (score 117):

For this you should use the [System.Security.SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx)

```
public SecureString GetPassword()
{
    var pwd = new SecureString();
    while (true)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo i = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (i.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (i.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
        {
            if (pwd.Length > 0)
            {
                pwd.RemoveAt(pwd.Length - 1);
                Console.Write("\b \b");
            }
        }
        else if (i.KeyChar != '\u0000' ) // KeyChar == '\u0000' if the key pressed does not correspond to a printable character, e.g. F1, Pause-Break, etc
        {
            pwd.AppendChar(i.KeyChar);
            Console.Write("*");
        }
    }
    return pwd;
}
```

Comment: This will only take me two places back. But what I need is that when I press Backspace the last character should be deleted. Just like the original functinality of backspace.

Comment: I needed to nest `if( pwd.Length > 0)` into the first else statement to stop people deleting the question :)

Comment: Similarly to Safron's comment on the currently accepted answer, the final `else` clause would benefit from a test `if (!char.IsControl(i.KeyChar))` (or at the very least `if (i.KeyChar != '\u0000')`).

Comment: How can I turn that password into a string?

Comment: [DE0001: SecureString shouldn't be used](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md)

Comment: @Amessihel While that document makes a good case for not using credentials, if you have to use them anyway, SecureString is better than nothing.

Answer (score 51):

Complete solution, vanilla C# .net 3.5+

Cut & Paste 
:)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace ConsoleReadPasswords
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.Write("Password:");

                string password = Orb.App.Console.ReadPassword();

                Console.WriteLine("Sorry - I just can't keep a secret!");
                Console.WriteLine("Your password was:\n<Password>{0}</Password>", password);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    namespace Orb.App
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds some nice help to the console. Static extension methods don't exist (probably for a good reason) so the next best thing is congruent naming.
        /// </summary>
        static public class Console
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Like System.Console.ReadLine(), only with a mask.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="mask">a <c>char</c> representing your choice of console mask</param>
            /// <returns>the string the user typed in </returns>
            public static string ReadPassword(char mask)
            {
                const int ENTER = 13, BACKSP = 8, CTRLBACKSP = 127;
                int[] FILTERED = { 0, 27, 9, 10 /*, 32 space, if you care */ }; // const

                var pass = new Stack<char>();
                char chr = (char)0;

                while ((chr = System.Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar) != ENTER)
                {
                    if (chr == BACKSP)
                    {
                        if (pass.Count > 0)
                        {
                            System.Console.Write("\b \b");
                            pass.Pop();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (chr == CTRLBACKSP)
                    {
                        while (pass.Count > 0)
                        {
                            System.Console.Write("\b \b");
                            pass.Pop();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (FILTERED.Count(x => chr == x) > 0) { }
                    else
                    {
                        pass.Push((char)chr);
                        System.Console.Write(mask);
                    }
                }

                System.Console.WriteLine();

                return new string(pass.Reverse().ToArray());
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Like System.Console.ReadLine(), only with a mask.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>the string the user typed in </returns>
            public static string ReadPassword()
            {
                return Orb.App.Console.ReadPassword('*');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It can always be more difficult :) Won't work on Mac/Linux because the newline is not recognised. Environment.NewLine has the string for a newline. So I modified this into: while (!Environment.NewLine.Contains(chr = System.Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar))

Answer (score 26):

Taking the top answer, as well as the suggestions from its comments, and modifying it to use SecureString instead of String, test for all control keys, and not error or write an extra "*" to the screen when the password length is 0, my solution is:

```
public static SecureString getPasswordFromConsole(String displayMessage) {
    SecureString pass = new SecureString();
    Console.Write(displayMessage);
    ConsoleKeyInfo key;

    do {
        key = Console.ReadKey(true);

        // Backspace Should Not Work
        if (!char.IsControl(key.KeyChar)) {
            pass.AppendChar(key.KeyChar);
            Console.Write("*");
        } else {
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && pass.Length > 0) {
                pass.RemoveAt(pass.Length - 1);
                Console.Write("\b \b");
            }
        }
    }
    // Stops Receving Keys Once Enter is Pressed
    while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
    return pass;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Mine ignores control characters and handles line wrapping:

```
public static string ReadLineMasked(char mask = '*')
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
    while ((keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true)).Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(keyInfo.KeyChar))
        {
            sb.Append(keyInfo.KeyChar);
            Console.Write(mask);
        }
        else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && sb.Length > 0)
        {
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);

            if (Console.CursorLeft == 0)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.BufferWidth - 1, Console.CursorTop - 1);
                Console.Write(' ');
                Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.BufferWidth - 1, Console.CursorTop - 1);
            }
            else Console.Write("\b \b");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. You may have to add code to make the **`DELETE` _character_** erase all entered text though. Its key sequence is `CTRL + BACKSPACE` and its char code is `0x7f`.

Answer (score 14):

This masks the password with a red square, then reverts back to the original colours once the password has been entered.

It doesn't stop the user from using copy/paste to get the password, but if it's more just about stopping someone looking over your shoulder, this is a good quick solution.

```
Console.Write("Password ");
ConsoleColor origBG = Console.BackgroundColor; // Store original values
ConsoleColor origFG = Console.ForegroundColor;

Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; // Set the block colour (could be anything)
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

string Password = Console.ReadLine(); // read the password

Console.BackgroundColor= origBG; // revert back to original
Console.ForegroundColor= origFG;
```

Comment: The only problem is that if you do backspace the background where you had characters stays red. I would rather go with setting ForegroundColor as origBG to have a Linux style password input.

Comment: You could also do `Console.CursorVisible=false` and set it back to previous value after. This would prevent someone to peak at password length.

Answer (score 13):

Reading console input is hard, you need to handle special keys like Ctrl, Alt, also cursor keys and Backspace/Delete. On some keyboard layouts, like [Swedish](https://superuser.com/questions/195433/vim-trouble-with-ctrl-on-scandinavian-keyboards) Ctrl is even needed to enter keys that exist directly on US keyboard. I believe that trying to handle this using the "low-level" `Console.ReadKey(true)` is just very hard, so the easiest and most robust way is to just to disable "console input echo" during entering password using a bit of WINAPI.

The sample below is based on answer to [Read a password from std::cin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1455007) question.

```
    private enum StdHandle
    {
        Input = -10,
        Output = -11,
        Error = -12,
    }

    private enum ConsoleMode
    {
        ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT = 4
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(StdHandle nStdHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out int lpMode);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, int dwMode);

    public static string ReadPassword()
    {
        IntPtr stdInputHandle = GetStdHandle(StdHandle.Input);
        if (stdInputHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No console input");
        }

        int previousConsoleMode;
        if (!GetConsoleMode(stdInputHandle , out previousConsoleMode))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "Could not get console mode.");
        }

        // disable console input echo
        if (!SetConsoleMode(stdInputHandle , previousConsoleMode & ~(int)ConsoleMode.ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "Could not disable console input echo.");
        }

        // just read the password using standard Console.ReadLine()
        string password = Console.ReadLine();

        // reset console mode to previous
        if (!SetConsoleMode(stdInputHandle , previousConsoleMode))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "Could not reset console mode.");
        }

        return password;
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

I found a bug in shermy's vanilla C# 3.5 .NET solution which otherwise works a charm. I have also incorporated Damian Leszczyński - Vash's SecureString idea here but you can use an ordinary string if you prefer.

THE BUG: If you press backspace during the password prompt and the current length of the password is 0 then an asterisk is incorrectly inserted in the password mask. To fix this bug modify the following method.

```
    public static string ReadPassword(char mask)
    {
        const int ENTER = 13, BACKSP = 8, CTRLBACKSP = 127;
        int[] FILTERED = { 0, 27, 9, 10 /*, 32 space, if you care */ }; // const


        SecureString securePass = new SecureString();

        char chr = (char)0;

        while ((chr = System.Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar) != ENTER)
        {
            if (((chr == BACKSP) || (chr == CTRLBACKSP)) 
                && (securePass.Length > 0))
            {
                System.Console.Write("\b \b");
                securePass.RemoveAt(securePass.Length - 1);

            }
            // Don't append * when length is 0 and backspace is selected
            else if (((chr == BACKSP) || (chr == CTRLBACKSP)) && (securePass.Length == 0))
            {
            }

            // Don't append when a filtered char is detected
            else if (FILTERED.Count(x => chr == x) > 0)
            {
            }

            // Append and write * mask
            else
            {
                securePass.AppendChar(chr);
                System.Console.Write(mask);
            }
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine();
        IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr();
        ptr = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(securePass);
        string plainPass = Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(ptr);
        Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(ptr);
        return plainPass;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

(My) [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PanoramicData.ConsoleExtensions) to do this, based on the top answer:

`install-package PanoramicData.ConsoleExtensions`

Usage:

```
using PanoramicData.ConsoleExtensions;

...

Console.Write("Password: ");
var password = ConsolePlus.ReadPassword();
Console.WriteLine();
```

Project URL: https://github.com/panoramicdata/PanoramicData.ConsoleExtensions

Pull requests welcome.

Comment: I used this for a small project.  Worked as expected.  Thank you

Comment: Works as promised.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version that adds support for the `Escape` key (which returns a `null` string)

```
public static string ReadPassword()
{
    string password = "";
    while (true)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        switch (key.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                return null;
            case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                return password;
            case ConsoleKey.Backspace:
                if (password.Length > 0) 
                {
                    password = password.Substring(0, (password.Length - 1));
                    Console.Write("\b \b");
                }
                break;
            default:
                password += key.KeyChar;
                Console.Write("*");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Jeez guys

```
    static string ReadPasswordLine()
    {
        string pass = "";
        ConsoleKeyInfo key;
        do
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                if (!(key.KeyChar < ' '))
                {
                    pass += key.KeyChar;
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
                else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && pass.Length > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(ConsoleKey.Backspace));
                    pass = pass.Remove(pass.Length - 1);
                    Console.Write(" ");
                    Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(ConsoleKey.Backspace));
                }
            }
        } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
        return pass;
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, what about backspace etc...?

Comment: Jeez is one word for this inanity fest :))

Answer (score 1):

You could append your keys to an accumulating linked list.

When a backspace key is received, remove the last key from the list.

When you receive the enter key, collapse your list into a string and do the rest of your work.

Comment: Sounds achievable but how will I remove the last character from the display.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes for backspace

```
        string pass = "";
        Console.Write("Enter your password: ");
        ConsoleKeyInfo key;

        do
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey(true);

            // Backspace Should Not Work
            if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                pass += key.KeyChar;
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            else
            {
                pass = pass.Remove(pass.Length - 1);
                Console.Write("\b \b");
            }
        }
        // Stops Receving Keys Once Enter is Pressed
        while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The Password You entered is : " + pass);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated Ronnie's version after spending *way too much time* trying to enter a password only to find out that I had my CAPS LOCK on!

With this version what ever the message is in `_CapsLockMessage` will "float" at the end of the typing area and will be displayed in red.

This version takes a bit more code and does require a polling loop. On my computer CPU usage about 3% to 4%, but one could always add a small Sleep() value to decrease CPU usage if needed.

```
    private const string _CapsLockMessage = " CAPS LOCK";

    /// <summary>
    /// Like System.Console.ReadLine(), only with a mask.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mask">a <c>char</c> representing your choice of console mask</param>
    /// <returns>the string the user typed in</returns>
    public static string ReadLineMasked(char mask = '*')
    {
        // Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/19770778/486660
        var consoleLine = new StringBuilder();
        ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
        bool isDone;
        bool isAlreadyLocked;
        bool isCapsLockOn;
        int cursorLeft;
        int cursorTop;
        ConsoleColor originalForegroundColor;

        isDone = false;
        isAlreadyLocked = Console.CapsLock;

        while (isDone == false)
        {
            isCapsLockOn = Console.CapsLock;
            if (isCapsLockOn != isAlreadyLocked)
            {
                if (isCapsLockOn)
                {
                    cursorLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
                    cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;
                    originalForegroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("{0}", _CapsLockMessage);
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorLeft, cursorTop);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = originalForegroundColor;
                }
                else
                {
                    cursorLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
                    cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;
                    Console.Write("{0}", string.Empty.PadRight(_CapsLockMessage.Length));
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorLeft, cursorTop);
                }
                isAlreadyLocked = isCapsLockOn;
            }

            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);

                if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    isDone = true;
                    continue;
                }

                if (!char.IsControl(keyInfo.KeyChar))
                {
                    consoleLine.Append(keyInfo.KeyChar);
                    Console.Write(mask);
                }
                else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && consoleLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    consoleLine.Remove(consoleLine.Length - 1, 1);

                    if (Console.CursorLeft == 0)
                    {
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.BufferWidth - 1, Console.CursorTop - 1);
                        Console.Write(' ');
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.BufferWidth - 1, Console.CursorTop - 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("\b \b");
                    }
                }

                if (isCapsLockOn)
                {
                    cursorLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
                    cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;
                    originalForegroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("{0}", _CapsLockMessage);
                    Console.CursorLeft = cursorLeft;
                    Console.CursorTop = cursorTop;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = originalForegroundColor;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        return consoleLine.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my simple version.
Every time you hit a key, delete all from console and draw as many '*' as the length of password string is.

```
int chr = 0;
string pass = "";
const int ENTER = 13;
const int BS = 8;

do
{
   chr = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
   Console.Clear(); //imediately clear the char you printed

   //if the char is not 'return' or 'backspace' add it to pass string
   if (chr != ENTER && chr != BS) pass += (char)chr;

   //if you hit backspace remove last char from pass string
   if (chr == BS) pass = pass.Remove(pass.Length-1, 1);

   for (int i = 0; i < pass.Length; i++)
   {
      Console.Write('*');
   }
} 
 while (chr != ENTER);

Console.Write("\n");
Console.Write(pass);

Console.Read(); //just to see the pass
```

Comment: `new string('*', pass.Lenght)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you're trying to make backspace delete both the visible * character on screen and the cached character in your pass variable?

If so, then just change your else block to this:

```
            else
            {
                Console.Write("\b");
                pass = pass.Remove(pass.Length -1);
            }
```

Comment: This will work fine except that the deletion of the character by backspace will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I just improve code from ask I simple and just work

```
    string pass = ""; //create empty password string
    Console.Write("Enter your password: ");
    ConsoleKeyInfo key;
    int passLen = 0; // base password length

    do
    {
        key = Console.ReadKey(true); //reading keyboard key

        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) Environment.Exit(0); // If key is escape console will close (optional)

        if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace && key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter) // on key with is not bacspase and enter 
        {
            pass += key.KeyChar; //password string add key value
            Console.Write("*"); // and print star as masked char 
            passLen++; // upgrading password length
        }
        else if (passLen > 0 && key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace) //if password have a any symbol and u press Backspace
        {   
                Console.Write("\b \b"); //Backspace delete star symbol and coursor back in line 
                passLen--; // password length is one less
                pass = pass[0..^1]; // new string passowrd is string without last charter 
        }
    } 
    while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter); // if you press enter this stop execute with your password

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("The Password You entered is : " + pass);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: now I explain code in best way I can

Answer (score -3):

```
 string pass = "";
 Console.WriteLine("Enter your password: ");
 ConsoleKeyInfo key;

 do {
  key = Console.ReadKey(true);

  if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace) {
   pass += key.KeyChar;
   Console.Write("*");
  } else {
   Console.Write("\b \b");
   char[] pas = pass.ToCharArray();
   string temp = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < pass.Length - 1; i++) {
    temp += pas[i];
   }
   pass = temp;
  }
 }
 // Stops Receving Keys Once Enter is Pressed
 while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);

 Console.WriteLine();
 Console.WriteLine("The Password You entered is : " + pass);
```

Comment: This answer does not add anything beyond what existing answers to. Additionally, good answers should typically explain the code, rather than just pasting code in to the answer box. Please read [answer]