# C# Advanced Console I/O

Tags: c#, console, io

I have multiple I/O tasks that I want to do with a console:

- Print out standard, non-editable text (`Console.WriteLine()`)
- Print out text that the user can edit (`?`)
- Allow the user to type, and be able to output text via the two methods above (`?`)

  - It would be nice if I could do [password masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404421/password-masking-in-c-console-application) too.

Anybody have any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit text like in a console-based text editor?

I think all that you need is in the Console class, have a look at its members:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could give curses a try, there is a [C# wrapper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/curses-sharp/) avaiable. Didn't tried it myself, though...

Answer (score 2):

Party like it's 1988 with Mono's getline. http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Aug-26.html

Answer (score 0):

Answer already submitted 
but the below code may be help

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    public static int i = 0;
    public static string[] S = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.Write("Please Select : "+S[i]);
        ConsoleKeyInfo K = Console.ReadKey(); 
        while (K.Key.ToString() != "Enter")
        {
            Console.Write(ShowOptions(K));
            K = Console.ReadKey();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Option Selected : " + S[i]);

        Console.ReadKey();
        }
    public static string ShowOptions(ConsoleKeyInfo Key)
    {

        if(Key.Key.ToString() == "UpArrow")
        {
            if (i != S.Length-1)
                return "\b\b" + S[++i];
            else 
                return "\b\b" + S[i];
        }
        else if (Key.Key.ToString() == "DownArrow")
        {
            if(i!=0)
            return "\b\b" + S[--i];
            else 
                return "\b\b" + S[i];
        }

        return "";
    }
}

}
```