# C# Console - hide the input from console window while typing

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm using `Console.ReadLine`to read the input of the user. However, I want to hide/exclude the inputted text on the console screen while typing. For example, when the user writes "a", it writes "a" to the console and then I will have a variable with the value "a". However, I don't want "a" to be written on the console's output.

How can I do that?

Comment: `Console.ReadLine` is setup in a way that it echoes the input straight back to the console. For special-use cases (like if you wanted to enter a password and didn't want people to see the letters typed), you must capture the characters one-by-one (as @ojblass pointed out) and store them into a variable yourself. Or if you prefer, you can display a series of '*' out to the console's output, or even replace them with flying monkeys if you want.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3404421/945456

Answer (score 43):

Here is a short implementation. thx @ojblass for the idea

```cs
System.Console.Write("password: ");
string password = null;
while (true)
{
    var key = System.Console.ReadKey(true);
    if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        break;
    password += key.KeyChar;
}
```

Comment: might be better to use a stringbuilder

Comment: @m4tt1mus I disagree. StringBuilder is only a performance boost when doing a large amount of string concatenation. Typing a password is not a large amount. Using StringBuilder would just add unnecessary extra code.

Comment: @CathalMF "Opinions vary on just how many strings you have to concatenate before you should start worrying about performance. The general consensus is around 10." https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/

Comment: @m4tt1mus Yes but not when we wait for user entry on each loop. It would have to be an unbroken loop to matter.

Comment: And what about pressing Ctrl-V to paste the text? Will the program receive the symbols as if they were typed in or will it receive just Ctrl-V key codes?

Comment: @JustAMartin Works with "Ctr+C/Ctrl+V". Made a short test (dotnet core console app).

Answer (score 19):

Console.ReadKey(true) hides the user key.  I do not believe Console.Read() offers such a capability.  If necessary you can sit in a loop reading keys one at a time until enter is pressed.  See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an example.

Answer (score 9):

I created this method from the code in the answer by [dataCore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001163/datacore) and the suggestion by [m4tt1mus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464251/m4tt1mus). I also added support for the backspace key.

```
private static string GetHiddenConsoleInput()
{
    StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
    while (true)
    {
        var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter) break;
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && input.Length > 0) input.Remove(input.Length - 1, 1);
        else if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace) input.Append(key.KeyChar);
    }
    return input.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just changed the foreground colour to black while the password was being inputted. I a newbie so it's probably a bad idea but it worked for the challenge i was trying

```
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to our system. Please create a UserName");
        var userName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Now please create a password");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        var password = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine("Okay, let's get you logged in:");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private static string GetPassword()
    {
        StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
        while (true)
        {
            int x = Console.CursorLeft;
            int y = Console.CursorTop;
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                break;
            }
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && input.Length > 0)
            {
                input.Remove(input.Length - 1, 1);
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x - 1, y);
                Console.Write(" ");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x - 1, y);
            }
            else if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                input.Append(key.KeyChar);
                Console.Write("*");
            }
        }
        return input.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to keep your neighbor from reading the password you can also play with the foreground color:

```
Console.Write("Enter root password:")
Dim oldColor As ConsoleColor = Console.ForegroundColor
Console.ForegroundColor = Console.BackgroundColor
rootPW = Console.ReadLine()
Console.ForegroundColor = oldColor
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of showing something different to the previous solutions and seeing as I love a good simple and dirty solution..

```
// Take input character
val = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
// Remove entered character from console
Console.Write("\b \b");
```

Obviously wrap in a loop and etc etc.

Very late to the party I know and a much less elegant solution compared with the rest but hopefully this might help someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

Improved version from [@Fredrik Fjällström](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7724509/fredrik-fj%c3%a4llstr%c3%b6m) post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59668053/2935383

His version is great because you can also see the cursor and set password-*** char if necessary.
But what is still missing is the suppression of non-printable characters.

```
    public static string GetPassword()
    {
        StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
        while (true)
        {
            int x = Console.CursorLeft;
            int y = Console.CursorTop;
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                break;
            }
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && input.Length > 0)
            {
                input.Remove(input.Length - 1, 1);
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x - 1, y);
                Console.Write(" ");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x - 1, y);
            }
            else if( key.KeyChar < 32 || key.KeyChar > 126 )
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Output suppressed: no key char"); //catch non-printable chars, e.g F1, CursorUp and so ...
            }
            else if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                input.Append(key.KeyChar);
                Console.Write("*");
            }
        }
        return input.ToString();
    }
```