# better end on keypress

Tags: c#, console

I am writing a console app and found this method to end a loop on a keypress:

`while (!Console.KeyAvailable){//do stuff}`

It works, but it echos the key that was pressed back to the prompt.  Is there a better method?

edit:

To clarify more, the loop runs and if hit the letter <kbd>j</kbd> the loop ends and the program exits.  However, I get the following output at the prompt:

`C:\>j`

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433980/c-sharp-console-hide-the-input-from-console-window-while-typing

Comment: @jdphenix not what im looking for, i edited my question to clarify

Comment: Can you please elaborate question? Do you want to break loop after key pressed, but key should not displayed on screen? Do you want solution for this?

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar yes. i dont want the keypress to show after the program exits

Comment: You need to add Console.ReadKey(true) after the loop to slurp the typed character.

Comment: @HansPassant that was it.  if you make it an answer, ill select it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit from a loop after a particular key is pressed, then instead of `Console.KeyAvailable` you can use the `Console.ReadKey()` function and check the return type of this function as an exit condition.

Here is the implementation.

```cs
while (true) {
    var keyPressed = Console.ReadKey(true);
    if (keyPressed.KeyChar == 'j') break;
    //do something
    Console.WriteLine("Key pressed: " + keyPressed.KeyChar);
}
```

For more details: [C# Console - hide the input from console window while typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433980/c-sharp-console-hide-the-input-from-console-window-while-typing)