# Process with Verb = "runas" does not start with the credentials defined in Arguments

Tags: c#, process.start, runas

This

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd")
            {
                Verb = "runas",
                UseShellExecute = true,
                Arguments = "/user:domain\\username"
            };
        var ps = Process.Start(psi);
```

does not start the command line window with the given credentials nor asks for password. I'd like to know how to use it properly.
I was told, that one shouldn't use the StartInfo.UserName, Domain and Password method because it's not safe.

Comment: what exactly is unsafe about it?

Comment: "Please DON'T save passwords inside your source code!" So I've been told.

Comment: no need to save it, you can promt the user for it by yourself and pass it to your `ProcessStartInfo` before actually starting it ;)

Comment: The concern isn't about using them at all, the concern is with embedding secrets into your script. There are many secure techniques to get credentials, keys, and other secrets into a script without storing the values in the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that it is insecure to use such built in .NET functionality: Just don't save plaintext passwords in and you're good to go. Just provide all the non-critical properties to your `ProcessStartInfo` just as .NET wants you to, and then promt the user for the password:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd")
{
    UseShellExecute = true,
    UserName = "username",
    Domain = "domain"
};

SecureString password = new SecureString();

Console.WriteLine("Please type in the password for 'username':");
var readLine = Console.ReadLine(); // this should be masked in some way.. ;)

if (readLine != null)
{
    foreach (var character in readLine)
    {
        password.AppendChar(character);
    }

    psi.Password = password;
}

var ps = Process.Start(psi);
```

However, as my comment states, you should mask the password-promt in some way. see [Password masking console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404421/password-masking-console-application) for an example on how to achieve this...