# Turn a string into password

Tags: c#, string, methods, console, passwords

```
static string ReadPassword(int length, char c)
```

The method should allow you to enter a string as a password. **length** is the minimum length of the password and **c** is the character displayed on the screen for each digit of the password.

Enter a password with at least 8 characters for use in the Main:

```
string pwd = ReadPassword(8, '●')
```

The user types the letters of his / her password. On the screen, however, do not appear letters , but the character that is stored in c, For example the bullet '●'.

**How do i build the program in such way that it writes * for each character typed in the console eaven though my method ends at return s;?**

Comment: Ok.. but.. you forgot to ask a question!

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: sorry, this is my assigment, and I dont really know where to begin.

Comment: _I dont really know where to begin_ By learning the basics or/and starting a research?

Comment: `"I dont really know where to begin"` by asking your instructor for clarification?

Comment: You definitely shouldn't begin by outsourcing your homework to Stack Overflow.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: @PronoyMukherjee _What do you want to do?..._ Huh?

Comment: @maccettura we had 13 different string method assignments, 12 of witch were mandatory, this is an extra assigment made especially harder then the other ones. The professor dose not suply help to this assigment. Im not asking for the code just a place to begin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password masking console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404421/password-masking-console-application)

Comment: yourTextBox.PasswordChar = '\u25CF';  this will give your desired bullet

Comment: @NineBerry I know how to do it like that, but everything must be programmed in a method that dose not write in the main. It must be declared in main like this "console.write(ReadPassword(8,'*');)"

Comment: @xxbbcc it's a program for witch we do not get extra credit, it's for those who are done with the first 12 assigments. I do have a broad idea how the program should look like, but I really have no idea how to buid it to write '*' instead of the pressed character without writing anything in main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the cursor position to input position or use `ReadKey(true)` Try this:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Set password: ");
        var password = ReadPassword(8, 'o');
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"Your password is: {password}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static string ReadPassword(int length, char c)
    {
        var left = Console.CursorLeft;
        var top = Console.CursorTop;
        var password = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            password.Append(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(left + i, top);
            Console.Write(c);
        }
        return password.ToString();
    }
}
```

You can find the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This works thanks, i've been trying for 2 hours and didn't manage to find the version of what I needed. The help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

```
class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            char ch;int len;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Length of the Password: ");
            len = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Character for Password:");
            ch = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
            printPassword(len, ch);
            Console.Read();
        }
        public static void printPassword(int len,char ch) {
            char ch1;String pass="";
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                pass += Console.ReadKey(true);
                Console.Write(ch);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, could I ask how you came to this answer, since its more important 
 or me as a student to be able to figure this out myself. Would you recomand any books on c#?

Comment: `Clean Code` from Martin and `Adaptive Code` from Gary McLean Hall are very nice books for beginners.

Comment: @cSteusloff thank you so mutch man, thats really nice of you.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw(v=vs.110).aspx

Check this link. From here I came to the Answer. I used it for my own console project once.

Comment: @PronoyMukherjee thanks man, it was explained nicely. For some reason I got a lot of shit for asking for help with this, im new so im not sure if i did smth wrong. It's nice to get some helpful responses.