# I'm trying to mask the characters entered in the console with '*' but it is just repeatedly printin asterisks, anyone know what i can do?

Tags: c#, echo, readkey

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Console.Write("password: ");
    string password = null;
    while (true){
      var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
      Console.Write("*");
      password += key.KeyChar;
      if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

> ```
> while (true){
> ```
>
> I'm trying to get it to read the key entered and then print an '*' but it is just endlessly printing *'s
>
> ```
> var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
> Console.Write("*");
> ```

Comment: try to use `flag` and instead `break` use `flag=false;` and in `while` use ` while (flag)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password masking console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404421/password-masking-console-application)

Comment: above code is working for me.

Comment: works for me too. with the problem of `Enter` also adding an asterisk. Easy fix