# Hide user input on password prompt

Tags: c++, console, iostream, cout, cin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read a password from std::cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413445/read-a-password-from-stdcin)

I don't work normally with the console, so my question is maybe very easy to answer or impossible to do .

Is it possible to "decouple" `cin` and `cout`, so that what I type into the console doesn't appear directly in it again?

I need this for letting the user typing a password and neither me nor the user normally wants his password appearing in `plaintext` on the screen.

I tried using `std::cin.tie` on a `stringstream`, but everything I type is still mirrored in the console.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/Seldaek/hidden-input

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From [How to Hide Text](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/43683/):

**Windows**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); 
    DWORD mode = 0;
    GetConsoleMode(hStdin, &mode);
    SetConsoleMode(hStdin, mode & (~ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT));

    string s;
    getline(cin, s);

    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}//main
```

cleanup:

```
SetConsoleMode(hStdin, mode);

tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
```

**Linux**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    termios oldt;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    termios newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);

    string s;
    getline(cin, s);

    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}//main
```

Comment: `tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);` is required for cleanup in Linuz too.

Answer (score 5):

You're really asking about two unrelated issues.
Calling `cin.tie( NULL )` decouples `std::cin` and `std::cout`
completely.  But it doesn't affect anything at a lower level.  And at the lowest level, at least under Windows and Unix, `std::cin` and `std::cout` are both connected to the same device at the system level, and it is that device (`/dev/tty` under Unix) which does the echoing; you can even redirect standard out to a file, and the console will still echo input.

How you turn off this echoing depends on the system; the easiest solution is probably to use some sort of third party library, like curses or ncurses, which provides a higher level interface, and hides all the system dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`getch()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) to get the input instead of using `cin`, so the input will not be shown (quoting wiki):

> int getch(void)   Reads a character directly from the console without
>   buffer, and without echo.

This is really C, not C++, but it might suit you.

Also, there's [another link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=168659) here.