# cin.get() allows characters to be inputted

Tags: c++, cin

I have C++ code that look like this:

```
void Typewriter(string strOk) {    
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < strOk.length(); x++) {
        cout << strOk[x];
        Sleep(50);

    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    Typewriter("OK, Hello. This is a first thingy. IDK.");
    Typewriter("This is the second line, also the second call to the function");
    cin.get();
    Typewriter("You pressed Enter! [Enter] next page");
    cin.get();
    Typewriter("Haha, no next page. Now, cya!");
    return 0;
}
```

It works just fine, except while `cin.get()` is waiting for an <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress, the user can enter other characters and they will *show up in the console.*. It kind of acts like `cin` but executes the next statement when  <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed. How do I restrict keyboard presses from being shown in the console and only react when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed?

Comment: You will need to use platform or OS specific functions.  Search StackOverflow for existing answers.  Something like "c++ keyboard press" or "c++ input nonblocking".

Comment: Q: How do I restrict keyboard presses from being shown in the console and only react when Enter is pressed?  A: Your best bet is to consider using a library like [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide user input on password prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899025/hide-user-input-on-password-prompt)