# Replacement to getch based code block in cpp

Tags: c++, linux, g++, c++17, turbo-c++

I stumbled upon a code from 2016 written in the Turbo C++ IDE in windows
It was to accept passwords

```
char pass;
    for (length = 0;;)
    {
        pass=getch();
        if (pass == 13)
        {
            break;
        }
        if ((pass >= 'A' && pass <= 'Z') || (pass >= 'a' && pass <= 'z') || (pass >= '0' && pass <= '9') || (pass == '!' || '@' || '#' || '$' || '%' || '^' || '&' || '*' || '(' || ')'))
        {
            str[length] = pass;
            ++length;
            cout << "#";
        }
    }
```

is there any replacement for this without the getch method for **linux** to show output like this ******** ? I tried scanf but that didnt work cause it took the whole input first and gave the output later

Comment: maybe this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899025/hide-user-input-on-password-prompt

Comment: yeah this seems to work like a normal password in linux theres no way to output ***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard replacement in C++.

Linux (and similar systems such as BSD), there is a legacy function `getpass` whose use is not recommended. I mention it because the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/getpass.html) of that function in glibc suggests following:

> This precise set of operations may not suit all possible situations. In this case, it is recommended that users write their own getpass substitute. For instance, a very simple substitute is as follows:
>
> ```
> #include <termios.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> ssize_t
> my_getpass (char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream)
> {
>   struct termios old, new;
>   int nread;
>
>   /* Turn echoing off and fail if we can’t. */
>   if (tcgetattr (fileno (stream), &old) != 0)
>     return -1;
>   new = old;
>   new.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
>   if (tcsetattr (fileno (stream), TCSAFLUSH, &new) != 0)
>     return -1;
>
>   /* Read the passphrase */
>   nread = getline (lineptr, n, stream);
>
>   /* Restore terminal. */
>   (void) tcsetattr (fileno (stream), TCSAFLUSH, &old);
>
>   return nread;
> }
> ```

Note that the example is written in C, and is not valid C++. Small changes are required, in particular there is a C++ keyword `new` being used as a variable name. Simply rename it to something else.

Also note that the behaviour is to not echo at all, rather than echo `*`. This is conventional in POSIX systems, and safer because the it does not reveal the length of the passphrase.