# How do I hide user input with cin in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, user-input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read a password from std::cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413445/read-a-password-from-stdcin)

I'm trying to make a simple password program so I can get familiar with C++, but I'm having a bit of a problem.  In this code, I ask the user for a password they choose, and then they enter it.  What I want to code to do is hide the input (**not** replace it with *s), but still show the cursor, and the text above, before, and after the password is entered, like this:

```
Please enter password: [don't show input]
Please re-enter password: [don't show input]
```

How can I do this?  I'm using Linux, so I won't be able to use any windows libraries (windows.h, etc).

Comment: Did you peruse the istream documentation for a way to set a no echo property?

Comment: @John, You won't find that in any standard C++ documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do this directly using cin. You have to go "lower". Try calling these functions:

```
#include <termios.h>

...

void HideStdinKeystrokes()
{
    termios tty;

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &tty);

    /* we want to disable echo */
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;

    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tty);
}

void ShowStdinKeystrokes()
{
   termios tty;

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &tty);

    /* we want to reenable echo */
    tty.c_lflag |= ECHO;

    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to call [`tcsetattr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/tcsetattr.html) and modify the `ECHO` flag.