# password masking in ubuntu in C++

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, passwords, masking

I recently made a program which uses `getch()` to mask the password entered. But it gives access as soon as the correct code is entered without waiting for enter key to be pressed. what changes should be done? Also, is `getch()` allowed in Ubuntu? If not, what alternative is to be used?

My code looks like this. I already gave default password in a different function.

```
char pass[4];
cout << "\nEnter Administrator Password: ";
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  pass[i] = getch();
  cout << "*";
}
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  if(admin_pass[i] == pass[i])
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know `getch()` is from **<conio.h>** which is Microsoft specific, unless you're referring to the [`getch()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) from **curses**.

Comment: I meant the one from <conio.h>. What's the one about **curses**?

Comment: [getch(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read a password from std::cin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413445/read-a-password-from-stdcin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `getpass()` as follows,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>


char *pass=getpass("\nEnter Administrator Password: "); 

if(strcmp(admin_pass,pass)==0) 
  return 1;
else 
  return 0;
```

The function `getpass()` is defined in the header file `unistd.h`.

Comment: `return !strcmp(admin_pass,pass);` although this might be harder to read by beginners.

Comment: Any special header file that is to be used?

Answer (score 2):

The [`getpass`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/getpass.html) function might help.

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is to use getch() in caution. `<conio.h>` is an very old library, and is frequently changed from OS to OS. For many cases, `read` is an alternative for `getch`.

See

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/7312/#msg33734

Comment: `read` alone doesn't solve the problem of echoing from the terminal.