# How to clear input in C++ Console commands

Tags: c++, input, console, console-application, codeblocks

In the console for C++, how can I make it so when you type your input, and hit enter, the input doesn't show up on the console. Heres my code.
Look at this gif gyazo, https://gyazo.com/8ac7196dbf3236d4a55ee1024809a7c9 
I don't want that "1" to appear when you press enter. I'm using Code::Blocks by the way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int input;
cout << "I want the number thats underneath this to not show up, but still be inputted." << endl;
cin >> input;

}//main
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413445/reading-a-password-from-stdcin

Comment: This is specific to the terminal you use. Nothing to do with standard c++.

Comment: @EmmanuelMathi-Amorim Not exactly as asked for.

Comment: I need a clearer example, im confused by the question you sent, i'm still new to c++ and I need a clearer example, could you unmark it off duplicate? or explain, thank you. @EmmanuelMathi-Amorim

Comment: There is no standard in C or C++ that allows you to block the user from seeing what he is typing in the terminal. However, there are platform specific methods of doing this. The code in the question I linked too allows you to hide inputted text on Windows and on Linux.